# PHP - Decode JSON

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get the token held in this variable `$data` - which I obtained via

```
$data = json_decode($result, true);
```

json:

```
{
    "response": {
        "status": "OK",
        "token": "goog:11229:116ewfd1c0f5c:goog",
        "dbg_info": {
            "instance": "53.google.com",
            "slave_hit": false,
            "db": "master",
            "parent_dbg_info": {
                "instance": "23.google.com",
                "slave_hit": false,
                "db": "master",
                "parent_dbg_info": {
                    "instance": "44.google.com",
                    "slave_hit": false,
                    "db": "master",
                    "time": 212.100215784,
                    "version": "1.19",
                    "warnings": [],
                    "slave_lag": 0,
                    "start_microtime": 123620305.0342
                }
```

I already decoded the JSON and it's held in $data

I tried to get

```
echo $data[response]->[token];
```

and

```
echo $data[response][token];
```

Comment: show your code to decode the json

Comment: show the line of code where you decode json into $data. it matters.

Comment: $data = json_decode($result, true);

Comment: @CodyRaspien then, follow Suchit's advice.

Comment: does `$result` contain the json you are quoting in the question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keys should be in quotes. Try like this:

```
echo $data['response']['token'];
```

ASSUMING your string like:

```
         $json='{"response":{"status":"OK","token":"goo:187089:586e5e5cc0666:goo","dbg_info":{"instance":"50.bm-goo.prod.ams1","slave_hit":false,"db":"master","parent_dbg_info":{"instance":"71.goo.prod.nym2","slave_hit":false,"db":"master","parent_dbg_info":{"instance":"44.goo.nym2","slave_hit":false,"db":"master","time":735.19611358643,"version":"1.17","warnings":[],"slave_lag":1,"start_microtime":1483628123.6313},"awesomesauce_cache_used":false,"count_cache_used":false,"uuid":"306aa2c0-f625-55c8-8984-db43b434b289","warnings":[],"time":1451.1139392853,"start_microtime":1483628123.557,"version":"1.17.150","slave_lag":0,"output_term":"not_found"},"awesomesauce_cache_used":false,"count_cache_used":false,"uuid":"48060f64-9b7c-50fd-a243-b17d3064a9a7","warnings":[],"time":1635.9009742737,"start_microtime":1483628123.4259,"version":"1.17.150","slave_lag":1,"output_term":"not_found","master_instance":"71.goo.prod.nym2","proxy":true,"master_time":1451.1139392853}}} ';

$data=json_decode($json,true);
 echo $data['response']['token'];//goog:11229:116ewfd1c0f5c:goog
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/266997ade14a60c281f63d3f9d9978e528a84f40)

Comment: Cool - when I do this, I output the entire json, not just token.

Comment: @RodrigoBoratto you can check the json here. http://json.parser.online.fr/. The json added in answer is right.copy paste the entire code and run in local to see the output.

Comment: @RodrigoBoratto then you should comment in question area.

Comment: This is my full JSON http://pastebin.com/tj8RzJSq  - I still can't retrieve the token value

Comment: @CodyRaspien i have update the answer with your data You can run the demo link also

Answer (score -1):

If you are using JSON_DECODE(var, true) to decode, the result will be an Associative Array (because of true in the second argument), so you have to do this:

```
echo $data["response"]["token"];
```

Full Example:

```
$json = '
{
   "response":{
      "status":"OK",
      "token":"goog:11229:116ewfd1c0f5c:goog",
      "dbg_info":{
         "instance":"53.google.com",
         "slave_hit":false,
         "db":"master",
         "parent_dbg_info":{
            "instance":"23.google.com",
            "slave_hit":false,
            "db":"master",
            "parent_dbg_info":{
               "instance":"44.google.com",
               "slave_hit":false,
               "db":"master",
               "time":212.100215784,
               "version":"1.19",
               "warnings":[

               ],
               "slave_lag":0,
               "start_microtime":123620305.0342
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
';
$data = json_decode($json, true);

echo $data["response"]["token"];
```

Comment: OP said otherwise, decoding as an associative array.

Comment: ops! changing for associative then.